# PostCSS Autoprefixer not working in Laravel 7.x

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-mix, postcss, autoprefixer

In [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#postcss), Laravel documentation says :

> By default, Mix leverages the popular Autoprefixer plug-in to automatically apply all necessary CSS3 vendor prefixes.

But when I write some css like below and compile it using sass, the output doesn't have any prefixed css!

```
display: grid;
box-sizing: border-box;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Here is my webpack.mix.js file configuration :

```
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .options({ processCssUrls: false });
```

I even used [this configuration](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/css-preprocessors#postcss-plugins) but again no prefixes!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which browser versions you want to support in your *package.json* file:

```
"browserslist": [
    "last 3 versions"
 ]
```

- [browserl.ist: a page to display compatible browsers from a browserslist string](https://web.archive.org/web/20200308131617/https://browserl.ist/?q=last+3+versions)
- [Browserslist: the config to share target browsers and Node.js versions between different front-end tools](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#full-list)

The default settings should be fine in most scenarios.

- [Laravel  Mix CSS Preprocessors](https://web.archive.org/web/20200308131419/https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/css-preprocessors)

<sub>**Source:** [Sti3bas](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/postcss-autoprefixer-not-working)</sub>

Comment: If there are default settings, then why is it necessary to specify browser versions explicitly in `package.json`? Shouldn't the defaults be being used?

Comment: By default, Mix will pipe all of your CSS through the popular [Autoprefixer PostCSS](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) plugin. As a result, you are free to use the latest CSS 3 syntax with the understanding that any necessary browser-prefixes will be applied automatically. The default settings should be fine in most scenarios, however it's also possible to tweak the underlying Autoprefixer configuration.